# Linux unexpected operator/operand while testing for files

Tags: linux, if-statement, ksh

I have the following simple ksh script used in Linux

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x
### Process list of *.dat files
if [ -f *.dat ]
then
print "about to process"
else
print "no file to process"
fi
```

I have the following *.dat files in my current directory:

```
S3ASBN.1708140015551.dat S3ASBN.1708140015552.dat S3ASBN.1708140015561.dat S3HDR.dat
```

Running file command shows the following:

```
file *.dat
S3ASBN.1708140015551.dat: ASCII text
S3ASBN.1708140015552.dat: ASCII text
S3ASBN.1708140015561.dat: ASCII text
S3HDR.dat:                ASCII text
```

However, when I run the ksh script, it shows the following:

```
 ./test
+ [ -f S3ASBN.1708140015551.dat S3ASBN.1708140015552.dat S3ASBN.1708140015561.dat S3HDR.dat ]
./test[9]: [: S3ASBN.1708140015552.dat: unexpected operator/operand
+ print  no file to process
 no file to process
```

Any clue why I am getting `unexpected operator/operand` and what's the remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is incorrect: you are testing if *.dat is a file.
The problem is: `*.dat` has a globbing operator `*` which creates the list of each item endig with `.dat`.
This test is only ran once, whereas you have multiple files so multiple tests tu run.

Try adding a loop:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
set -x
### Process list of *.dat files
for file in *.dat
do
  if [ -f $file ]
  then
    print "about to process"
  else
    print "no file to process"
  fi
done
```

In my case:

```
$> ls *.dat
53.dat  fds.dat  ko.dat  tfd.dat
```

Outputs:

```
$> ./tutu.sh 
+ [ -f 53.dat ]
+ print 'about to process'
about to process
+ [ -f fds.dat ]
+ print 'about to process'
about to process
+ [ -f ko.dat ]
+ print 'about to process'
about to process
+ [ -f tfd.dat ]
+ print 'about to process'
about to process
```